# ssrs Horizontal range chart label

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working in ssrs 2008 R2. I need to plot the series label on the top of horizontal range bar. [image]

But the label is displayed on the left side of the bar.
I tried CustomAttribute Property Label Property and SmartLabel Property. Always the label is look like this:
[image]

Is there any other option to set the label on the top. Thanks in advance.